# Задача на циклы C#

Tags: c#, циклы

```
int len = 100, sum;
for (int i=0; i< len; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j< len; j ++) { 
        Console.Write (i);   
        Console.Write (j);
    };
};
```

Нужно вывести 2 числа через цикл в цикле, от 0 до 99. Всё идеально, если просто задать 1 цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < len, i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Но когда вводишь 2-й цикл внутри первого, он выводит по 100 раз пока условие второго выполняется, как решить эту задачу?

Просили пояснение:
Поясняю – нужно получить 2 числа от 0 до 100, не важно как их отображать, суть в том, чтобы использовать 2 цикла, это первое условие, дальше задача продолжается, но сам не до конца понимаю, а именно :
Нужно эти 2 числа сложить друг с другом, после того как из 2 циклов мы имеем: `i = 0,1,2,3...99; j = 0, 1 , 2 , 3.... 99;`
нужно каждое число сложить друг с другом

```
0+1=1
0+2=2
0+3=3....
..
1+0= 1
1+1= 2
1+2 = 3
...
```

Дальше все эти числа разделить на четные и не четные, это уже просто, делением на 2 и через условие if

Comment: не понятно что должно выводиться. правильно сформулируйте вопрос

Comment: @Санаев наверно двумя циклами вывести числа от 0 до 99 по порядку

Comment: Сначала определитесь что хотите сказать патом можете оценить мои ответы

Comment: `Нужно вывести 2 числа через цикл в цикле, от 0 до 99` Что вы имеете ввиду под 2мя числами?

Comment: Покажите на примере какие должны быть выходные данные, из сформулированного вопроса это не очевидно и задача кажется бессмысленной. Уверенны ли вы вообще, что вам нужны вложенные циклы?

Comment: Добавил пояснение в условие

Answer (score 2):

Можете так, но задача звучит бессмысленно

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(i*10 + j);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: наверное это самое логичное решение очень нелогичной задачи )

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, вам нужно вот это:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",i,j);
}
```

Comment: `WriteLine` поддерживает форматирование из коробки

Comment: аа вот что имел в виду автор..

Comment: как вариант еще добавить когда i = 0, то выводить только j

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, т.к. ТС не объясняет полной сути задания.

```
int length = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if(i+j%1 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i+j); // Складываем наши итераторы,
                                    // и если модуль суммы чисел от единицы равен нулю
                                    // выводим.
        }
    }
}
```

Тест: https://ideone.com/f4wnaw

Comment: если так но можно и без этого `if(i+j%1 == 0)` насколько я понимаю это `i+j%1 == 0` всегда  возврщает `true` не так ли?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan почему? `true` пока `i == 0` :) Упоротое решение однако, уверен, что на проверке лабы оно точно будет уникальным!

Comment: @yolosora да вы прави но в остальном цикл будет работать **9900** без результатно

Comment: @VardanVardanyan можно воткнуть `else return;` :)

Comment: @yolosora ну да можно всегда что то делать ))) все в наших руках :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это очередная тупая задача для демонстрации работы `for` рзанимы сбособами.Я тут поговорил с Вангой и думаю что ему нужно что вроде такого

```
int len = 10, j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (; j < len;)
            {
                Console.Write("First Number " + i + "\t" + "Second Number " + j);
                break;
            }
            j++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял задачу то вот решение

```
for (int i = 0; i < len, i++) {
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: исходя из задания должно быть два цикла